# angularjs resource does not return the right value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in my controller in angularjs

```
    $scope.likeit = function(entry) {
        entry.like = !entry.like;
        var ret = VoteResource.save(entry);
        console.log("Return Object")
        console.log(ret)
        console.log("======================================")
        console.log("Return Like Property")
        console.log(ret.like_count)
        return ret
    };
```

When I tried to trigger this function in my view and examine in console this is the output

```
    Return Object 
       Resource {comment_count: 0, confess: "Hello world!!! kk", created_at: "2013-06-11T00:26:25Z", feeling_id: 0, hug_count: 0…} 
       comment_count: 0
       confess: "Hello world!!! kk"
       created_at: "2013-06-11T00:26:25Z"
       feeling_id: 0
       hug_count: 0
       id: 1
       like_count: 0
       metoo_count: 0
       updated_at: "2013-06-11T23:48:16Z"
       user_id: null
       __proto__: Resource

       ====================================== 
       Return Like Property 
         1
```

My question why is it ret.like_count return 1. In first console log the resource value of like_count is zero (0) but In ret.like_count output it return 1. Why? So how do I access like_count in resource?

Comment: What is VoteResource?  Does it have a toString() that displays those fields when you do console.log?  What does the line for like_count look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. resource is asynchronous so what I use the $q (promise) injection this is the partial code to solve the problem and some link [$resource in angularjs does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045771/resource-in-angularjs-does-not-work-properly)

```
    save: function(confession) {
        var defferred = $q.defer()
        resource.save(confession,

            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                confession.like_count =  response.like_count
                defferred.resolve(response);
            },
            function(response) { defferred.reject(response)}

        );

    }
```