# is there an AngularJS version of jQuery's document ready

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and was able to create a basic page that create's a list of people with some checkboxes that allow you to choose them.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvBWn/)

The problems is that when I change the getAllPeople function to pull from a database

```
 $http.post('angular.cfc?method=returnSerializeQuery').success(function(data) {
       $scope.allPeople = data;
     });
```

instead of building the array in the js the html loads to fast and loads with a blank list.  if I then search the list shows up.  I know that the $http call is too slow to keep up with the document load.

I have to use $timeout but I can't seem to get it to work an the dataset may sometimes take longer than other.  If there is a Angular version of $(document).ready() I can't seem to find it.

I am also guessing that since this is my first fully functional page I am have not completely set it up right and that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post().success callback function, after `$scope.allPeople = data;` add `$scope.groupToPages()`, since ng-repeat is watching `pagedItems`, not `allPeople`.

Comment: Okay, you had another $scope property that needed to be updated: add `$scope.filteredPeople = $scope.allPeople;` before `$scope.groupToPages()`.  Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/Gtkmm/) -- I added $timeout to simulate HTTP delay.

Answer (score 2):

If the idea is to delay the page rendering until data is fetched from the server, you have  good answers (and examples) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356185/angular-js-delaying-controller-initialization) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker).

The main idea:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {    
    $scope.data = {};
}

Ctrl.resolve = {
    data: function($http) {
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/path/to/some/data'});
    }
};

var myApp = angular.module('app', [], function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/template.html',
        controller: Ctrl,
        resolve: Ctrl.resolve
    });
});​
```

Also check this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dTJ9N/54/