# How to delay instantion of a specific controller(not a route)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, asynchronous, promise

I would like to have a directive which behaves as typical ng-controller, but I want it to be called once a promise is resolved, not sooner.
In HTML this could be written like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ctrl-promise="p">
```

p could be any promise on parent scope.
I know there is a way to delay instantiation of a controller for a route(as answered here: [Angular.js delaying controller initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356185/angular-js-delaying-controller-initialization)), but I would much prefer to specify this per controller rather than per route. 
I know I could use ng-if with p as atribute, but is there other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the stuff inside the div to exist, just without the controller controlling it, until the promise is resolved?

Here is a directive which will create a controller when a promise is resolved:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('delayController', function($controller, $q) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      $q.when(scope.$parent.$eval(attr.delayControllerPromise)).then(function() {
        var ctrl = $controller(attr.delayController, {
          $scope: scope
        });
        elm.children().data('$ngControllerController', ctrl);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You can use it like this:

```
<div delay-controller="MyCtrl" delay-controller-promise="myPromiseExpr()">
</div>
```

Comment: This works when I have my controller function on parent scope, but when I have it defined with regular angular.module('app', []).controller('myCtrl', ...) it obviously won't inject it there. I have tried injecting it by calling $injector.get(attr.delayController) but that just returns an error: Unknown provider: MyCtrlProvider <- MyCtrl, why isn't it injecting as it should?

Comment: I should have read docs http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$controller before I thought that it requires a function. Thanks for sticking around!

Comment: I have trouble with scope.$eval(attr.delayControllerPromise). In the plnkr it resolves to undefined instead of the promise object, so the controller is not delayed at all. Why?? I even tried creating a parent controller where I stored the promise too, but no luck...

Comment: Try scope.$parent.$eval - since the directive creates a child scope.