# image not updating using ng-src in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller, I call a service. This service makes a request to a PHP file that gives me a URL to an image.

The reason for this is the image resides inside a "Media Vault" meaning I need to generate a hashed URL like so in order to view it:

`http://xxxx.vo.llnwd.net/o35/s/xxx/test/thumbs/slide1.jpg?e=1365006137&h=5852aeaf5beeeebff05a601801b61568`

The URL above has already expired so you won't see anything from that specific link.

My image tag is like so:

`<img id="thumbnail" class="glow" ng-src="{{currentThumb}}" width="200" height="150"/>`

currentThumb in my controller is:

```
$scope.currentThumb = ImageService.getImage({
    'type' : 'thumb',
    'index' : $scope.currentIndex + 1,
    'location' : $scope.location
});
```

and my service looks like this:

```
app.factory('ImageService', function($http)
{
    var image = null;
    return {
        promise:null,
        getImage: function($data)
        {
            this.promise = $http.post('resources/auth.php',$data, {timeout:20000}).success(function(response)
            {
                image = response;
                log(response);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

The current ImageService successfully returns a URL (at least it shows the url in the console) and when clicking the log result in the console, the image loads fine. Any reason why the image isn't updating?

Comment: I've tried `thumbnail.src = ImageService.getImage({...});` also with no luck. I get `http://localhost/vjs/undefined 404 not found`

Comment: How about putting a return statement in `getImage()` after you get your response. Or are you resolving your promise?

Comment: I've tried `return image;` after I set `image = response` and still nothing. It's like `$scope.currentThumb = ImageService.getImage({...});` isn't actually setting anything. Must be a problem with my service?

Comment: What about the `this.promise` part, are you calling the method to resolve that promise? Try just calling the `$http.post` on its own without setting it equal to `this.promise`. Also include the `return image;` part.

Comment: no method to resolve the promise that I am aware of. I am new to angular so I don't know what I'm doing half the time lol. Anyway, I removed the `this.promise =` part and left in `return image;`, tried it, no luck. Removed it, no luck

Comment: I'll make a fiddle..maybe you can get it working somehow

Comment: here we go @Justen http://jsfiddle.net/HYDmj/ had to add some headers to my php file. Just keep an eye on the javascript console

Comment: I noticed if I `return $http....` I get an object back with the `data` in it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HYDmj/1/

Comment: 7 hours later! Geez, awesome man, if you post this as an answer I will accept it. thanks so much! I can move on finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you need to call this, but another way that might be better is to call that `ImageService.getImage()` in a resolve block of the controller. That way its all loaded before the controller and view taken care of.

**jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/HYDmj/1/

**view**

```
<div ng-app="main">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <h1>currentThumb</h1>
      <img ng-src="{{currentThumb.data}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

**code**

```
var app = angular.module('main',[]);

app.factory('ImageService', function($http)
{
    image = null;
    return {
        getImage: function($data)
        {
            image = $http.post('http://dopserv1.dop.com/test/auth.php', $data, {timeout:20000})
            return image
        }
    }
});

function ExampleController($scope, ImageService)
{
    $scope.currentThumb = ImageService.getImage({
        'type' : 'thumb',
        'index' : 1,
        'location' : 'http://digitalout.vo.llnwd.net/o35/s/mobilevforum/test/'
    });
}
```

Comment: What is a resolve block? These images are loaded on demand. Basically if they mouse over an object, depending on which one it is, loads a different thumbnail

Comment: Oh alright then, it's not a use case for it. Here's a couple answers of mine about the resolve block though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker/12312015#12312015
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307501/q-defer-and-promises-and-how-to-use-them-to-load-the-data-for-a-controller-befo/13408143#13408143

Comment: Ah ok gotcha. I understand what you mean. Basically load/render everything prior to displaying the view. Yeah in this case, I am not able to do so. Thanks again for answer at hand. Helped me out tremendously

Comment: Yeah exactly, glad to help.