# How can I start fetching data from the server as quickly as possible?

Tags: angularjs

How can I start fetching data from the server as quickly as possible with Angular?

Currently, most of my page is populated asynchronously via a directive "fooload" placed at the root element:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp" fooload ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
    <head>
        /* bunch of CSS, and other resources */
    </head>
```

Which loads data into the scope via an http GET request:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives').
   directive('fooload', function ($http) {
     return {
         link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
             $http.get('/foo').success(function (data) {
             scope.foo = data;
     });
     }
     };
});
```

Looking at the network panel, this call is being made in the browser AFTER the requests for the resources referenced in head. How can I make the call to load /foo data as quickly as possible on page load (if possible, even before loading angular itself)?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? Could you describe your usecase?

Comment: I want to pull data from the server to populate the page. It takes a while to load (e.g. 1 sec.). Thus, I want to send the request as soon as possible. This is data that will continue to be polled so long while the user has the page open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by:

a) fetching the data even before angular loads and storing it in a global variable (I hate using a global variable, but I couldn't think of another way.)

b) manually bootstrapping angular upon load of this data (my app doesn't work at all without the data)

```
        var $data;
        var ajax_transport = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Callback for AJAX call
        function responseProcess() {
            if (ajax_transport.readyState !== 4) {
                return;
            }
            if (ajax_transport.responseText) {
                $data = JSON.parse(ajax_transport.responseText);
                    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
                });
            }
        }
        // Sending request
        ajax_transport.open("GET", "/mydata", true);
        ajax_transport.onreadystatechange = responseProcess;
        ajax_transport.send();
```

Note: it's important to remove the tag ng-app="myapp" in your template to avoid automatic bootstrapping.

c) Using the data in my angular app:

```
        scope.setupSomething($data);
```

d) Also, to ensure that this data call begins before any other resource load, I started using a resource loader. I liked HeadJs (http://headjs.com/) the most, but the angular folks seem to like script.js (https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/index-async.html)

Criticism or improvements welcome.

Comment: This worked for me and improved load times significantly, but would love to hear a better way.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to Angular, obviously Angular cannot start loading files before Angular has loaded itself. But if the resource (eg `/foo`) is cacheable by the browser you could add it to a manifest file: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a new service that gets the resource and then bootstraps the document for angular upon success callback from the server.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   calllService(function () {
      angular.bootstrap(document);
   });
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12657669/1885896

Comment: Thanks for the response Brian. I'm not quite sure how this would be significantly faster than a directive? element.ready() is a wrapper of JQuery .ready() which waits until the full DOM is loaded. So I think the call out to pull my data would still only happen after every other resource (CSS, JS, etc.) is fully loaded.

Comment: To my knowledge you are correct. Is a 'loading' display out of the question?

Comment: It's not out of the question. Though, my current setup results in a 500ms delay which I want to avoid.