# AngularJS UI-Router: preload $http data before app loads

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need help from AngularJS experts that have worked with ui-router plugin. Can some provide a plunker example that works on preloading a $http data request before the app runs?

I did some research, but closest I came are these two stack overflows:

[AngularJS: How to load json feed before app load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308178/angularjs-how-to-load-json-feed-before-app-load)

[Delaying AngularJS route change until model loaded to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker/11972028#11972028)

I am less than a week into angularJS, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How could an angular app use $http before the app runs? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 14):

From https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

You can use `resolve` to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. `resolve` is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.

If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value **before** the controller is instantiated and the $routeChangeSuccess event is fired.

The `resolve` property is a map object. The map object contains key/value pairs of:

- key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.
- factory - {string|function}:

  - If string, then it is an alias for a service.
  - Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a promise, it is resolved before the controller is instantiated and its value is injected into the controller.

**Examples:**

Each of the objects in `resolve` below must be resolved (via `deferred.resolve()` if they are a promise) before the controller is instantiated. Notice how each `resolve` object is injected as a parameter into the controller.

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    resolve: {

        // Example using function with simple return value.
        // Since it's not a promise, it resolves immediately.
        simpleObj: function () {
            return { value: 'simple!' };
        },

        // Example using function with returned promise.
        // This is the typical use case of resolve.
        // You need to inject any services that you are
        // using, e.g. $http in this example
        promiseObj: function ($http) {
            // $http returns a promise for the url data
            return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl' });
        },

        // Another promise example. If you need to do some 
        // processing of the result, use .then, and your 
        // promise is chained in for free. This is another
        // typical use case of resolve.
        promiseObj2: function ($http) {
            return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl' })
               .then(function (data) {
                   return doSomeStuffFirst(data);
               });
        },

        // Example using a service by name as string.
        // This would look for a 'translations' service
        // within the module and return it.
        // Note: The service could return a promise and
        // it would work just like the example above
        translations: "translations",

        // Example showing injection of service into
        // resolve function. Service then returns a
        // promise. Tip: Inject $stateParams to get
        // access to url parameters.
        translations2: function (translations, $stateParams) {
            // Assume that getLang is a service method
            // that uses $http to fetch some translations.
            // Also assume our url was "/:lang/home".
            translations.getLang($stateParams.lang);
        },

        // Example showing returning of custom made promise
        greeting: function ($q, $timeout) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve('Hello!');
            }, 1000);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    },

    // The controller waits for every one of the above items to be
    // completely resolved before instantiation. For example, the
    // controller will not instantiate until promiseObj's promise has 
    // been resolved. Then those objects are injected into the controller
    // and available for use.  
    controller: function ($scope, simpleObj, promiseObj, promiseObj2, translations, translations2, greeting) {
        $scope.simple = simpleObj.value;

        // You can be sure that promiseObj is ready to use!
        $scope.items = promiseObj.items;
        $scope.items = promiseObj2.items;

        $scope.title = translations.getLang("english").title;
        $scope.title = translations2.title;

        $scope.greeting = greeting;
    }
})
```

Comment: This is a good answer. To add to it - I use a single, `abstract` parent state which resolves any global dependencies. All other states exist as child states of that. One gotcha here is that the parent still needs a `ui-view` with all the child `ui-views` within that. After that you simply declare the parent's resolved dependencies within your child state's controllers as normal.