# AngularJS > ui.router using a promise ONLY when data is ready.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have followed the guidelines on angular-ui/ui-router wiki, to only load my images and text when the data is ready.

I don't get any errors, but it doesn't seem to be working. 
I'm new to Angular JS, so please excuse my lack to expertise.

My Plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4jZuBwm8TI42U6ZvWIPJ?p=preview

The code below is slightly different from my Plnkr (due to providing a working demo).

index.js

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ui.router'])
      .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
          })
          .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'app/about/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl'
          })
          .state('work', {
            resolve: {
              customPromise: function($q, $timeout) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function() {
                  deferred.resolve('all assets have loaded!');
                }, 1000);
                return deferred.promise;
              }
            },
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div ui-view="portfolio" class="page-work" autoscroll="true" data-loading="{{1}}"></div>'
          })
          .state('work.details', {
            url: '/work/:workId',
            views: {
              'portfolio@work': {
                templateUrl: 'app/work/work.html',
                controller: 'WorkCtrl'
              }
            }
          });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      });
```

work.controller.js

```
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp');

    app.controller('WorkCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $location, customPromise) {

        $scope.customPromise = customPromise;

        if (!$stateParams.workId) {
            $location.path('/');
        }

        $http.get('projects/' + $stateParams.workId + '.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.work = data;
            $scope.pageClass = 'page-work'; // only use to add class for ui view

            //function for next previous

            var currentWorkIndex;
            var l = $scope.allWorks.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if ($scope.allWorks[i].id === $stateParams.workId) {
                    currentWorkIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var prevWorkIndex = (currentWorkIndex !== 0) ? (currentWorkIndex - 1) : (l - 1);
            var nextWorkIndex = (currentWorkIndex !== l - 1) ? (currentWorkIndex + 1) : (0);
            $scope.prevWork = $scope.allWorks[prevWorkIndex].id;
            $scope.nextWork = $scope.allWorks[nextWorkIndex].id;


        });

    }]);
```

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to put the actual requests inside the resolve.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209107/angularjs-ui-router-preload-http-data-before-app-loads

Comment: Thanks for your answer tpie. I thought that by using `customPromise : function` I was inferring the scope in my work.controller (customPromise). I'm not sure of exactly what I have to do.  I looked through the ui.router wiki, and still don't get where I have to go.  Should I wrap my entire `customPromise` in the controller around the code where I use my `$http` request?

Comment: check my answer...mind you I just fixed your plunker.  I didn't use an ajax call, but you can do that on your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aUFPylNXQL3awLFmvzqk?p=preview)**

You have to inject the result of the resolve using the controller of the state.  Then you can use that binding in your view like you normally would.

You need this in your `state`

```
controller: function($scope, customPromise) {
        $scope.message = customPromise;
      }
```

Now, in your HTML you can bind `{{message}}`.

[Resolve Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Study the example there if you are not clear.  Note that there is a necessary correlation between what happens in `resolve` and injecting it into the `controller` of the `state` further down.

Comment: Thanks again tpie, I think I have now grasped what I have to do.  One last thing, is it possible to call the entire work div `{{work}}` or do I have called each `{{work.item}}` in which case I would `$scope.eachItem = customPromise;`  which would result in a long list of items to scope. Sorry for my lack of understanding, its my first ever use of Resolve/Promise combo.

Comment: when you say the 'entire work div', what do you mean?

Comment: the entire contents of work.html `<div class="work {{work.class}}" data-loading="{{1}}" ui-view="portfolio">` to the closing `</div>`.

Comment: go to chat - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75626/ui-router-using-a-promise