# $routeParams doesn't work in resolve function

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker) technique to load data. So I have created the following resolve function:

```
NoteController.resolve = {
    note: function($routeParams, Note) {
         return Note.get($routeParams.key);
    }
}
```

The problems is that `$routeParams.key` is `undefined` at the moment of `resolve` function execution. Is it correct/bug? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

You need to use `$route.current.params.key` instead. The `$routeParams` is updated only *after* a route is changed. So your code should look along those lines:

```
NoteController.resolve = {
    note: function($route, Note) {
         return Note.get($route.current.params.key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Why do I need $routeParams then?

Comment: I guess that http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams are nice API when a route was already matched and changed. But it is true that it is a bit confusing...

Comment: You can use `$routeParams` inside the controller

Comment: for people using `ui-router` and coming here: `$stateParams` is way to go

Comment: If you're using something like the `Ionic` framework, you will use `$stateParams.key` inside your resolve function since it uses `ui-router` as @beret said. Took me a while to realize..

Comment: Just a note, if you still using $routeProvider, you have to do `$route.current.params.param;` to get the param