# Angular JS - set and get query string parameter on $stateProvider state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I think this is just basically a question of syntax, but I have this routing set up:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('addAlbum', {
        url: "/albums/create/:artistId",
        templateUrl: "public/albums/views/album.tpl.html",
        controller: "createAlbumController",
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Create Album'
        },
        resolve: {
            albums: function (publicArtistServices) {
                return publicArtistServices.getAlbums(1);

            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

And I need that getAlbums() method to use the artistId passed in on the URL:

**return publicArtistServices.getAlbums({need artistId from URL here});**

I tried guessing at it by using *return publicArtistServices.getAlbums($state.params[0]);* but that just threw a "$state is not defined" error.

What's the right syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `$state` parameter (to "inject" it into your function):

```
        albums: function ($state, publicArtistServices) {
            return publicArtistServices.getAlbums($state.params[0]);
        }
```

If that doesn't work, use `$route.current.params.artistId` as shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433335/584846

Comment: Hm. Neither $state.params (after injection - can't believe I forgot to do that!) nor $route.current.params worked. However, per a comment on that link you referenced ("for people using ui-router and coming here: $stateParams is way to go"), I was able to get it to work using: function (publicArtistServices, $stateParams) { return publicArtistServices.getAlbums($stateParams.artistId); }

Comment: kudos to @hanothan for finding `$stateParams` too

Answer (score 5):

`$stateParams` is what you want to use for this.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('addAlbum', {
    url: "/albums/create/:artistId",
    templateUrl: "public/albums/views/album.tpl.html",
    controller: "createAlbumController",
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Create Album'
    },
    resolve: {
        albums: function ($stateParams, publicArtistServices) {
            return publicArtistServices.getAlbums($stateParams.artistId);
        }
    }
});
```

}]);

Comment: Oh, man, I didn't see this answer before I marked the other one correct. But yes, this is exactly the code that worked for me.

Comment: I feel like maybe I should mark this as the correct answer, even though the other answer is what lead me to solve the problem.

Comment: You should mark this correct since $stateParams is really what should be used here :)