# Angularjs Passing variable through resolve function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Right now I have a Auth Factory set up to run when my State goes to `cloud`. I am trying to pass the `:cloud_id` to that `authCheck()` function but I don't know how.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to change this:

```
resolve: { authenticated: authenticated }
```

To something like this:

```
resolve: { authenticated: authenticated(cloud_id) }
```

**Here is my code:**

```
.factory('Auth', function($http, $state, $q) {

    var factory = { authCheck: authCheck };
    return factory;

    function authCheck(cloud_id) {
        return $http.post('/auth/check', {id:cloud_id});
    }

})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cloud');

    var authenticated = ['$q', 'Auth', '$rootScope', function ($q, Auth, $rootScope) { 
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        Auth.authCheck(cloud_id).then(function(){ deferred.resolve(); }, function(){ deferred.reject(); });
        return deferred.promise;
    }];

    $stateProvider

        .state('cloud', {
            url: '/cloud/:cloud_id',
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html',
            controller: 'cloud',
            resolve: { authenticated: authenticated }
        })

})
```

Comment: You can inject $route in your resolve function and get the params out of there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13433335/373655

Comment: Thanks @rob, that last comment about `ui-router` and `$stateParams` helped a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject and use the [`$stateParams`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateparams-1) like this:

```
var authenticated = ['$q', 'Auth', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', function ($q, Auth, $rootScope, $stateParams) { 
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Auth.authCheck($stateParams.cloud_id).then(function(){ deferred.resolve(); }, function(){ deferred.reject(); });
    return deferred.promise;
}];
```

See [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WzHFQDyimuF5bSoRPBGD?p=preview).