# Loading page with AngularJS routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use Angular routes for creating small website for mobile.
Is there any way to add loading icon while loading a partial and swap the entire page to the right when switching? (like in native mobile app animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But change:

- $beginRouteChange to $routeChangeStart
- $endRouteChange to $routeChangeSuccess

and things will work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Misko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker/11972028#11972028) about delaying route changing. He links to an example, too which is helpful. Basically, you have to add to your routing logic a `resolve` function which will allow you to prevent showing of the new route until asynchronous calls are resolved, and observing the `$beginRouteChange` and `$endRouteChange` on the `$rootScope` ([example code here](http://mhevery.github.com/angular-phonecat/app/js/app.js))