# Angularjs resolve with controller as string

Tags: angularjs

My style of writing angular controllers is like this (using controller name instead of function)

```
angular.module('mymodule', [
])
    .controller('myController', [
        '$scope',
        function($scope) {
            // Some code here

        }
    ]);
```

What I need now is when providing i routes I want to define resolve part:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/someroute', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/someroute.html', 
        resolve: myController.resolve}) // THIS IS THE CRITICAL LINE
```

Since controller is defined as a name how to accomplish resolve part bellow?

To clarify more in details I want to load some data from server before route is resolved and then use these data in controller.

**UPDATE:** To be more precise I want each module has its "resolve" function that will be called before root with that controller is executed. Solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker) (answered by Misko Hevery) does exactly what I want but I don't have controllers as functions but as a names.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The controller definition and resolve parts are to be specified separately on the route definition.

If you define controllers on a module level you need to reference them as string, so:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/someroute', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/someroute.html', 
        controller: 'myController',
        resolve: {
          myVar: function(){
            //code to be executed before route change goes here
          };
        });
```

The above code also shows how to define a set of variables that will be resolved before route changes. When resolved those variables can be injected to a controller so taking the example from the snippet above you would write your controller like so:

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myVar', function($scope, myVar) {
            // myVar is already resolved and injected here
        }
    ]);
```

This video might help as well: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6KITGRQujQ

Comment: @AndrejKaurin you can inject services to both your controller and resolve functions, if this is what you are asking... Could you be more precise?

Comment: Inside when(), should `'myController',` be `controller: 'myController',`?

Comment: @MarkRajcok indeed. Fixed it.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource I get an error about myVarProvider is unknown. Any ideas why?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: What's exactly the meaning of the resolve key?  "myVar" in this Case?

Comment: I too get provider unknown when I provide a string for the `controller` attribute of the route.  However if I use a function instead, the resolve attribute gets injected in successfully and everyone is happy.

Comment: I just went through this same problem and found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/6nA4MEKyKAc - basically I also needed to remove the ng-controller from my view and let the route add it along with the resolved data

Comment: Awesome, i didn't know that i can inject variable from resolve section of the route directly into controller, i was using $route['current']['locals'] to get the variable from resolve definition

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource is it possible to add multiple controllers in the resolve such that  `controller: 'myController', 'secondController`, `thirdController` ?

Answer (score 13):

@pkozlowski.opensource 's answer works, but I don't really want to mess up my routing and and controllers, because I always keep it separated (from Yo Generator). Actually, we can also have controller and resolve(r) all as `string`/name (NOT function).

```
angular.module('mymodule', [
])
  .controller('myController', [
      '$scope', 'myModelCombination'
      function($scope, myModelCombination) {
          // myModelCombination[0] === (resolved) myModel 
          // myModelCombination[1] === (resolved) myModel2

      }
  ])
  .controller('myController2', [
      '$scope', 'myModel'
      function($scope, myModel) {
          // Some code here

      }
  ])
  .factory('myModel', [
      '$scope',
      function($scope) {
          // return a promise

      }
  ])
  .factory('myModel2', [
      '$scope',
      function($scope) {
          // return a promise

      }
  ])
  .factory('myModelCombination', [
      '$scope', 'myModel', 'myModel2'
      function($scope) {
          return $q.all(['myModel', 'myModel2']);

      }
  ]);
```

Then in your routing file this should be added

```
$routeProvider.when('/someroute', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/someroute.html', 
    resolve: ['myModel'] //ALWAYS IN ARRAY)
});
$routeProvider.when('/myModelCombination', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/someroute2.html', 
    resolve: ['myModel'] //ALWAYS IN ARRAY)
});
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider

Comment: myModel factory should return promise? Then how to return more promises via single factory (myModel in this case)? Or I should create new factory for every resolve.

Comment: Yes, each factory should return one and only one thing, either value or promise, unless you want to wait for everything and return all of it in $q.all(). Answer edited.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  Can you a show a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

This would work too

```
var MyController = myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myData', function($scope, myData) {
  // Some code here
}]);

MyController.resolve = {
  myData: ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/foo/bar')
      .success(function(data) {
        defer.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function(error, status) {
        defer.reject(error);
      });

    return defer.promise;
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@TruongSinh answer worked for me and is way nicer than having additional functions in the router. I tweaked it a little as it was returning the deferred object instead of the actual resolved data.

```
$routeProvider.when('/someroute', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/someroute.html', 
    controller: 'SomeController',
    resolve: {
       myModel: 'myModel'
    }
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post your entire solution here? I'm trying to do the same thing (returning a deferred object on resolve) and having difficulties to get it to work. Thanks.