# Using Resolve to show template when JSON returned in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a URL which gets hit and the model of the controller is data from an API call. At the moment by the time the template is rendered the data hasnt come back so I get a blank page.

I looked into and apprently Resolve is the approach to take but I've not had much luck.  Below is what I have but I'm very new at Angular so it maybe completely the wrong approach.

```
//app.js    
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('barbato', []).
           config(function ($routeProvider) {
               $routeProvider.
                   when('/', {
                       controller: 'ReposController',
                       templateUrl: '/Content/templates/repos.html',
                       resolve: {
                           myVar: function(repoService) {
                               return repoService.getItems();
                           }
                       }
                   }).
                   otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
           });

    app.factory('repoService', function ($http) {

        return {
            getItems: function () {
                $http.get('http://localhost:12008/getrepodata/jchannon').then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
        };
    });

})();




//repo.js    
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('barbato');

    var repooController = app.controller(
        'ReposController', ['$scope','myVar', function ($scope, myVar) {
            $scope.items = myVar;
        }
    ]);

})();
```

Comment: indeed resolve is the way to go. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker)

Comment: Not sure `return response.data;` is doing what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent entirely too much time today trying to figure out how to get this to work.  I found [this thread in the angularjs group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/QtO8QoxSjYw) and reworked the example provided by Pawel Kozlowski.

Basically, the trick is to use an anonymous factory method in the resolve function.  Otherwise, I guess you could just inject the function into the controller

[Here's the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MAvBo36oRIGJ9Y4i1Zj0?p=preview)

Comment: I've tried adding the 'then'to my controller but myVar gets injected as undefined into my controller. Any ideas?

Comment: have you seen this example on SO, it looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker

Comment: not sure how to do that as I reference my controller via string not object

Comment: Thanks will give it a go. I saw a similar approach here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980805/angularjs-resolve-with-controller-as-string but I get the error myVarProvider unknown

Answer (score 2):

You should do a little modification in your code

```
resolve: {
            myVar: function (repoService) {
                return repoService.getItems().then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        }


app.factory('repoService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getItems: function () {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:12008/getrepodata/jchannon');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined. looks like repoService.getItems() is undefined for some reason

Comment: im able to get the result perfectly using above methods if problem persists kindly set up a plunker of fiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

When working with resolves, you need to return the promise object. The view waits for the promise to resolve. Change your getItems function as follows.

```
app.factory('repoService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getItems: function () {
            var p = $http.get('http://localhost:12008/getrepodata/jchannon');
            p.then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
            return p;
        }
    };
});
```