# Angularjs : call services method inside a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this simple function js getItems(), inside I call a services items.getItems(..) ,
I would like that the function return me a data. I tried to associate the var to function but the result is undefined

```
function getItems() {
            var resolvedValue;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            items.getItems(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
            });
            deferred.promise.then(function(result) {
             resolvedValue=result; // it contains my information
            });
            console.log('v  alue%0' , resolvedValue); // it's undefined here!!!
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`items.getItems` is async, so you have to use `$q.promise`

```
function getItems() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  items.getItems(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(items);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Read more here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

Comment: When I print the  deffered.promise I don't see the data

Comment: As said, please read more http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q to use a promise, usually `promise.then(function)`, or you can resolve it in the controller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980805/angularjs-resolve-with-controller-as-string/17039181#17039181

Comment: I read and i understood to do this :deferred.promise.then(function(result) { resolvedValue=result;}); but it is not visible outside the function.....it is not possible to do return resolvedValue

Comment: As said, you do not return the value, you return the promise. That's what the promise is for. Please make a full fiddle with this service and another service or controller, where you make use of this service, we'll see how you can take the value from a promise.