# Angular - populate list with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am working on a web app, and I want to show data in a list, by category.  I am getting back AJAX data that has a title, and a category.  The code to get that is like this:

```
angular.module('getImageData', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('images', function ($resource)
  {
      return $resource('/ImageData/GetImages', {}, {
          query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
      });
  });
```

and then like this:

```
$scope.imageData = images.query(function (response)
{
    // This has become superfluous
    return response;
});
```

The AJAX call us occurring and I can see my data in Chrome.

Then here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="image in imagedata">
        <a href="">{{image.Title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I intend to do this:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="image in imagedata | filter : {TypeFilter : 'a' }">
        <a href="">{{image.Title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but for now I'm keeping it simple.

The list is never rendered.  This is the HTML I see in chrome:

```
<ul>
  <!-- ngRepeat: image in imagedata -->
</ul>
```

I am assuming this means it ran before the data came back.  How do I make it wait ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the images have a `TypeFilter` attribute?

Comment: try this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243506/angularjs-resolve-data-before-showing-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake in `image in imagedata`. It should be `image in imageData`

You also do not need to write callback function for `query`

```
 $scope.imageData = images.query();
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
$scope.imageData = images.query(function (response)
{
    // This has become superfluous
    return response;
});
```

to this:

```
$scope.imageData = images.query(function (response)
{
    $scope.imageData = response;
});
```