# Update view only when the json is received completely from ajax call in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm new to angularJS and still learning.
I'm trying to create a navbar in the header which gets the data from ajax call.

However, it shows `{{obj.pageData}}` until data is completely received.
It is very annoying to see this everytime I refresh the page!

How could I avoid it to show `{{obj.pageData}}` in the view and rather update it directly when the entire data is received from JSON?

Here's the sample code:

View:

```
<nav ng-app="topNavApp" ng-controller="navCtrl" class="nav">
  <div class="nav-center">
    <!--<li ng-repeat="obj in pageData.allChildList" ng-model="parentNav" ng-mouseover="parentNav=true" ng-mouseleave="parentNav=false"> -->
    <div ng-repeat="obj in pageData.allChildList" class="hiding-div" ng-mouseover="showDiv()" ng-mouseleave="hideDiv()" > 
      <div>
        <a ng-href="{{obj.pagePath}}" class="main-link multiple menu-link">{{obj.pageTitle}}</a>
        <!--<span class="main-link mobile" aria-labelledby="{{obj.pageTitle}}" aria-expanded="false">{{obj.pageTitle}}</span>-->

        <!--<span ng-repeat="child in obj.secondLevelVoList" class="childNav" ng-show="parentNav">--> 
        <div class="farm-links" ng-show="hovering">
          <!--<a class="prev-link" aria-labelledby="{{obj.pagetitle}}">{{obj.pageTitle}}</a>-->
          <div ng-repeat="child in obj.secondLevelChildList" class="groups-links">
            <a ng-href="{{child.pagePath}}" class="group-title">{{child.pageTitle}}</a>
            <!--<span class="group-title mobile" aria-expanded="false">{{child.pageTitle}}</span>-->
            <ul ng-repeat="subchild in child.thirdLevelChildList" class="group-links">
              <li class="second-link">
                <a ng-href="{{subchild.pagePath}}">{{subchild.pageTitle}}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('topNavApp', []).controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', function($scope, $timeout, $http){
    $http.get("/content/projdata/myJSONData.json").then(function(response){
        $scope.pageData = response.data;
    })['catch'](function(){
        console.log('failed');
    });
}]);
```

Please let me know in case of additional details required.

Comment: In your routing you can use "resolve". so when routing changes it will make http call, resolve promise then load your views.

Comment: I like @RaviKumar 's answer if you are using routing, but it doesn't appear that you are.   a How about ng-if="pageData" on your div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the angular [ng-Clock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive to prevent the brief display of the angular html template.

```
<div class="nav-center" ng-cloak>

</div>
```

Another option is to use `ng-bind` instead of `{{}}`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a condition for controlling when the data should be shown. For this you can use whether [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

Like this:

```
<div ng-if="pageData" ng-cloack ng-repeat="obj in pageData.allChildList" class="hiding-div" ng-mouseover="showDiv()" ng-mouseleave="hideDiv()" >
    <!--- ... -->
</div>
```

In this example AngularJS evaluates the expression `ng-if="pageData"` and **it will** only **show the div when `pageData` is truthy** .

In addition you can use [ng-cloack](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) in order to avoid any possible flickering of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Angular Resolve** which until data is received and then only it renders the data.

Check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243506/angularjs-resolve-data-before-showing-view)