# Loading user context before controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, promise, restangular

I developed an [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) app and I've a REST API for fetching app resources from my AngularJS app. When the user logs himself, I save his access token in a cookie. If he refreshes the page, I want to get back user information from the token like:

```
mymodule.run(function ($rootScope, $cookies, AuthService, Restangular) {
    if ($cookies.usertoken) {
        // call GET api/account/
        Restangular.one('account', '').get().then( function(user) {
            AuthService.setCurrentUser(user);
        });
    }
});
```

AuthService:

```
mymodule.factory('AuthService', function($http, $rootScope) {
    var currentUser = null;

    return {
        setCurrentUser: function(user) {
            currentUser = user;
        },
        getCurrentUser: function() {
            return currentUser;
        }
    };
});
```

But if the user accesses a controller which needs a user variable:

```
mymodule.controller('DashboardCtrl', function (AuthService) {
     var user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
});
```

the controller code was executed before the end of the API call so I've a null var. Is there a good solution to wait on user data loading before starting controllers?

I've found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker/11972028#11972028) but I'm looking for a more global method to initialize app context.

Comment: I think resolve is the way to go in this scenario as mentioned by Max.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way I like to handle this, assuming that Restangular returns the new promise from `then` (I haven't used Restangular).  The promise can be stored somewhere like on `AuthService` and then used later in the controller. First, add a property to `AuthService` to hold the new promise:

```
return {
    authPromise: {},  // this will hold the promise from Restangular
    // setCurrentUser, getCurrentUser
    // ...
```

When calling Restangular, save the promise and be sure to return the user data so that the controller can access it later, like this:

```
AuthService.authPromise = Restangular.one('account', '').get()
                          .then( function(user) {
                              AuthService.setCurrentUser(user);
                              return user; // <--important
                           });
```

Lastly, create a new promise in the controller that will set the `user` variable.:

```
mymodule.controller('DashboardCtrl', function (AuthService) {
    var user;
    AuthService.authPromise.then(function(resultUser){
        user = resultUser;
        alert(user);
        // do something with user
    });
});
```

**Demo**: [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/zA5yF/) where I've simulated an AJAX call with `$timeout`. When the timeout concludes, the promise resolves.

Answer (score 1):

You could try have the authentication method on a parent controller. Then in the resolve method in the routing you could go `resolve:DashboardCtrl.$parent.Authenticate()`.