# How to add a resolve property to an Angular controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add a `resolve` property to an AngularJS controller that I have defined as depicted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12312015/262868

However, unlike the way he defines his controller, I have it like this:

```
var mod = angular.module('controllers', [])
mod.controller('PhoneListController', ["$scope", function($scope) {
    foo
    bar
    …
}]);
```

How would I add a resolve property to the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, using your syntax, you want to get hold of your PhoneListController object so you can define It's resolve property, right?

You can do this:

```
var phoneListCtrl = mod.controller('PhoneListController', ["$scope", function($scope) {
    foo
    bar
    …
}]);

phoneListCtrl.resolve = {

    //code here

}
```

Comment: yes, I realized that was quite a dumb question to ask after I found the solution while watching the egghead.io videos.

Comment: No such thing as dumb question :)