# AngularJS - prevent $location change without flickering

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have tried both `$locationChangeStart` and `$routeChangeStart`, but none of them work - they either cause flickering (switchign urls) or don't work at all. what am I doing wrong here?

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event,future,current) {
    if (!user.isAuthenticated()){
        $location.path('/login');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    if (!user.isAuthenticated()) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }
  });
```

see this punker http://plunker.co/edit/SnBuFPXSLMBd8G9R0KXl?p=preview

Comment: If your `isAuthenticated` function is a promise or has other http overhead, the flickering is just a result of race condition between the user action and route validity.

Comment: There is also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the way you cancel the location change. It's the **ng-animate** on the ng-view that causes the flickering. You can still see it when you just switch locations without having the auth validation.