# Delaying route change until data is loaded in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

In Angular the $routeProvider resolve property allows delaying of route change until data is loaded. Given the route model hook in Ember returns a promise I was wondering how that stuff was done in Ember

Here it's what I mean in angular [Delaying AngularJS route change until model loaded to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker)

A link with a sample code would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just recently this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2740) introduced *Async transitions* to ember.js. With this change you can do all sort of things, like for example delaying a route's transition if data is still underway. A route has now all sorts of hooks available to do just want you want.

As an example *(taken from the gist mentioned below)* in the `afterModel` hook you could do something like this to only transition to the `post.show` route if you actually have data:

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(posts, transition) {
    if (posts.length === 1) {
      this.transitionTo('post.show', posts[0]);
    }
  }
});
```

Since this new features are still very *young* you need to use the [latest master](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest.js) to have it available. For more info on how to use the API please [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589).

Hope it helps

Comment: I saw some comments about async transitions, but just comment. Thanks very much