# AngularJS: $routeProvider when resolve $http returns response obj instead of my obj

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resolver, route-provider

I'm trying to resolve a couple ajax calls so that data my controller needs is available before it (and a directive it furnishes) execute. The order of execution is working, however, instead of returning the object I create, the result injected into my controller is $http's response object:

```
{
  config: { … },
  data: { … },
  headers: { … },
  status: 200
}
```

My code essentially looks like:

```
app.config([
  '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider)
  {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/path', {
        …,
        "resolve": {
          "data": [
            '$http',
            function($http)
            {
              return $http
                .get('/api/data')
                .success(function(data,status) { return data.rows[0]; })
                .error(function(data,status)   { return false; });
            }
          ]
        }
      });
  }
]);
```

Am I daft? Shouldn't the return value from $http's success actually be what is returned by $http?

I also tried

```
…
"resolve": {
  "data": [
    '$http',
    function($http)
    {
      var response;
      $http
        .get('/api/data')
        .success(function(data,status) { response = data.rows[0]; })
        .error(function(data,status)   { response = false; });
      return response;
    }
  ]
}
```

But then the `data` object injected into my controller was undefined (I'm guessing because $http is asynchronous and `resolve` was not blocked by $http—so it returned before $http was ready).

P.S. The synchronicity of $http should be definable in its options object!!

## Solution

```
app.config([
  '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider)
  {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/path', {
        …,
        "resolve": {
          "data": [
            '$http',
            function($http)
            {
              return $http
                .get('/api/data')
                .then(
                  function success(response) { return response.data.rows[0]; },
                  function error(reason)     { return false; }
                );
            }
          ]
        }
      });
  }
]);
```

Thanks to [Ajay beniwal's pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706764/758177) and [Mark Rajcok's pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706419/angularjs-routeprovider-when-resolve-http-returns-response-obj-instead-of-my#comment25803901_17706419).

P.S. `then()` is documented on [**$q**'s page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q#Description).

Comment: You need to return a promise.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker, the community wiki answer.

Comment: I was previously using `$http.get('…').then()` (which I think is a `$promise` method) but I need `success` and `error` methods (which I don't see for `then`. (I really don't want to set an arbitrary delay/timeout—just continue when its done, grr).

Comment: If the answer is in there, why not post it as an actual answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $http @returns {HttpPromise} Returns a {@link ng.$q promise} object
>   with the
>           standard `then` method and two http specific methods: `success` and `error`. The `then`
>           method takes two arguments a success and an error callback which will be called with a
>          response object. The `success` and `error` methods take a single argument - a function that
>           will be called when the request succeeds or fails respectively. The arguments passed into
>           these functions are destructured representation of the response object passed into the
>           `then` method. The response object has these properties:

Comment: Would be great if an example of how to use `then` and its callbacks was given in the docs :/

Comment: Ohh, there's an example in <a href="http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q#Description">`$q`'s docs</a>

Comment: "promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using promise chaining)."

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L317

TLDR–return whatever you want from $q.then successCallback/errorCallback mentioned above in the **Solution** above.