# AngularJS: Resolving not in RouteProvider but in Controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I saw some sample code here [Delaying AngularJS route change until model loaded to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker)

And straight away I though this was the right way to go, I need to have my controller LOAD only when a resolve is finished loading, normally most of the examples around tell you to put the code under resolve in the routeprovder as an inline function, but this sounds wrong. The controller needs it so why not have the controller implement the function to resolve. This sounded just what I was looking for ie. This seems to use the prototype pattern ??

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, phones) {
  $scope.phones = phones;
  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}

PhoneListCtrl.resolve = {
  phones: function(Phone, $q) {
    // see: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/DGf7yyD4Oc4
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Phone.query(function(successData) {
            deferred.resolve(successData); 
    }, function(errorData) {
            deferred.reject(); // you could optionally pass error data here
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

Problem is I have my controller like so

```
'use strict';

angular.module('TestApp')
  .controller('ItemsCtrl', function ($scope) {
});
```

So how do I apply a new function on the controller when my controller is declared inside a module ?

What I really need is something like

```
 TestCtrl.resolve = {
      items: function( $q) {
          ..........
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
```

This then would allow me to have in my routeprovider..

```
  when('/items', {
    templateUrl: 'views/items.html', 
    controller: 'TestCtrl', 
    resolve: 'TestCtrl.resolve'}). // Need to use ' around resolve?
```

But I am confused how I would get this to work ?

I would really love any feedback, I am at a loss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not possible to define like 'TestCtrl.resolve' if you want to use resolve  with .controller syntax then you have to define inline within route provider . The advantage of inline resolve in routeprovider is that you can reuse controller easily but using same controller and changing the logic in resolve function

Comment: Ok, thanks, So in fact the correct way to go and insert it into the Routeprovider.

Comment: yes its perfectly fine to insert in routeprovider it will allow to reuse your controllers

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a service:

```
resolve: {data : function(service) {
  return service.getData();
}}
```

Comment: This is my preferred method.

Comment: But what if you need something from $routeParams? For example I want to resolve the app (/api/1/apps/:appId), for which I need to know the $routeParams.appId

Comment: @zeronone take dependency on $route, and access $route.current.params in your resolve-method