# ng-repeat fails to execute correctly angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So i'm fairly new to angular and what i'm trying to do is take a json collection that is obtained from a RESTful call and loop through each one to display their value while associating its designated id in a href.

below you will find what I have tried:

```
<div class="span2">
        <!--Sidebar content-->

        Search: <input ng-model="query">
        Sort by:
        <select ng-model="orderProp">
            <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
            <!--option value="age">Newest</option>
            <option value="-age">Oldest</option-->
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <!--Body content-->
        <ul class="documents">
            <li ng-repeat="document in documents | orderBy:orderProp" class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#/rest/{{document.document_id}}">{{document.title}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <pre>{{ documents | json }}</pre>
    </div>
```

the Shttp call:

```
    function DocListCtrl($scope, $http)
{
    console.log('getting documents data');
    $http.get('/*RESTful call here*/').success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.documents = data;
    });
    $scope.orderProp = 'name';
}
```

when I run the page i get my list no problem using the

```
<pre>{{ documents | json }}</pre>
```

but the ng-repeat fails to implement.

EDIT

here is an example of the Json I am working with.

```
{
  "next": {},
  "items": [
    {
      "document_id": 3177554002,
      "title": "title of some item"
    }
]
}
```

What exactly am I doing incorrectly with the ng-repeat call that fails to list my data the way i wish?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What does your JSON response look like?

Comment: And what error did you see?

Comment: @MikeRobinson the Json has been added

Comment: @sza No specific error is thrown in the js console. It just fails to loop through the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your JSON, I see your ng-repeat isn't quite correct. You need to reference the `items` array inside the documents object when iterating, like so:

```
<ul class="documents">
    <li ng-repeat="document in documents.items | orderBy:orderProp" class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#/rest/{{document.document_id}}">{{document.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or if you want to make it simpler, bind `data.items` to `documents` instead of just `data` and then keep your existing template. This will also ensure that your `orderBy` keeps working.

Comment: I just realized the problem not 5 minutes ago and was in the process of looking for the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972028/1449799 you want to consider using the reolve property of the routeprovider. notice the small gotcha (the solution there is slightly outdated, $defer has been renamed to $timeout) [Delaying AngularJS route change until model loaded to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker#comment26957141_11972028)