# Hide template while loading in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the better solution to hide template while loading data from server?

My solution is using `$scope` with boolean variable **isLoading** and using directive `ng-hide`, ex: `<div ng-hide='isLoading'></div>`

Does angular has another way to make it?

Comment: I think this solution is good enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you do it is perfectly fine (I prefer using state='loading' and keep things a little bit more flexible.)

Another way of approaching this problem are promises and `$routeProvider resolve` property.
Using it delays controller execution until a set of specified promises is resolved, eg. data loaded via resource services is ready and correct. Tabs in Gmail work in a similar way, ie. you're not redirected to a new view unless data has been fetched from the server successfully. In case of errors, you stay in the same view or are redirected to an error page, **not** the view, you were trying to load and failed.

#### You could configure routes like this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.config([

  '$routeProvider',

  function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/test',{
      templateUrl: 'partials/test.html'
      controller: TestCtrl,
      resolve: TestCtrl.resolve
    })
  }

])
```

#### And your controller like this:

```
TestCtrl = function ($scope, data) {
  $scope.data = data; // returned from resolve
}

TestCtrl.resolve = {
  data: function ($q, DataService){
    var d = $q.defer();

    var onOK = function(res){
      d.resolve(res);
    };

    var onError = function(res){
      d.reject()
    };

    DataService.query(onOK, onError);

    return d.promise;
  }
}
```

#### Links:

- [Resolve](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve)
- Aaa! Just found an excellent (yet surprisingly similar) explanation of the problem on SO [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker)

Answer (score 9):

You can try an use the ngCloak directive.

Checkout this link http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Answer (score 1):

That's how I do:

```
$scope.dodgson= DodgsonSvc.get();
```

In the html:

`<div x-ng-show="dodgson.$resolved">We've got Dodgson here: {{dodgson}}. Nice hat</div>`

`<div x-ng-hide="dodgson.$resolved">Latina music (loading)</div>`