# Controller not fetching service data

Tags: angularjs

I have a `Service` and a `Controller`. The controller calls a function, `getItems()` on the `Service`. The `Service` returns an `array` of data.

However, the controller appears to not be receiving this, oddly enough.

Controller:

```
ItemModule.controller('ItemController', ['$scope', 'ItemService',
    function ($scope, ItemService) {

        $scope.items = [];

        $scope.getItems = function() {
            $scope.items = ItemService.getItems();
        }

        $scope.getItems();

    }
]);
```

Service:

```
ItemModule.service('ItemService', ['$rootScope', '$http', 
    function($rootScope, $http) {

        this.getItems = function() {
            $http.get($rootScope.root + '/products').success(function(data) {
                // This prints it out fine to the console
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            });
        }

    }
]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$http.get` is asynchronous and `success` is a callback. `return`ing from it is wrong (does not do what you expect it to). Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call#answer-14220323

Comment: Your problem would be solved for now by returning the HTTP promise, i.e.: `return $http.get(...existing code without change...)`

Comment: also not returning object you create in service, so when call `ItemService.getItems();` should see error that the method is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and **dirty** fix would be like that:

```
ItemModule.service('ItemService', ['$rootScope', '$http', 
function($rootScope, $http) {

    return {
        getItems : function(scope) { 
            $http.get($rootScope.root + '/products').success(function(data) {
                scope.items = data;
            });
        }
    }

}
]);
```

and then in your controller just call:

```
 ItemService.getItems($scope);
```

But if your controller is a part of route (and probably is) it would be much nicer to use `resolve` (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker)).