# How to bind data in json to li using Angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, webmethod

am try to develop an application using angular js in which i take take data from database and populate li using that data

for that i write a WebMethod as fallow

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string getname()
    {
        SqlHelper sql = new SqlHelper();

        DataTable dt = sql.ExecuteSelectCommand("select cust_F_name,Cust_L_Name from customer");

        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        }
        dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr);
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return json.Serialize(dict);


    }
```

which return data in json form

am use the fallowing js to bind

```
var DemoApp = angular.module('DemoApp', []);

DemoApp.factory('SimpleFactory', function () {
    var factory = {};
    var customer;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home.aspx/getname",

        data: JSON.stringify({ name: "" }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, status) {
            customer = $.parseJSON(data.d);

        },
        failure: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    });


    factory.getCustomer = function () {
        return customer;
    };
    return factory;
});

DemoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, SimpleFactory) {
    $scope.Customer = SimpleFactory.getCustomer();
});
```

and my view is as fallow

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="DemoApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Name<input type="text" data-ng-model="Name" />{{ Name }}
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="customer in Customer | filter:Name">{{ customer.cust_F_name }} -
                {{ customer.cust_L_name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it not working it will work fine if i hard code the data in factory but when i bring data using ajax call it will not work am unable to understand why it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why it's not working?

- you cannot just attach a variable to the scope when it's value is waiting for on asynchronous call.
- when you use 3rd-party libraries that changes the scope you must call $scope.$apply() explicitly

#### prefer $http over $.ajax and use promises!

```
DemoApp.factory('SimpleFactory', function ($http) {
  return {
    getCustomer: function(){          
      return $http.post('Home.aspx/getname',{ name: "" });
    })
  }
}

DemoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, SimpleFactory) {
    SimpleFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer){
      $scope.Customer = customer;
    },function(error){
      // error handling
    });
});
```

### If you still want to use $.ajax

- you must explicitly call $scope.$apply() after the response
- you must use promises or callbacks to bind to scope variables.

### If you want to first fetch data from the server and than load the view

- @Misko Hevery has a great answer: [Delaying AngularJS route change until model loaded to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker/11972028#11972028)

#### It's not related to your problem but load jquery before you load angular.js

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i try ur ans still it not gives the out but then a make some changes then i get the out put but it not acceptable for that i added new [que][1] please ans it 

 [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059294/unable-to-bind-data-get-from-database-in-view-using-angularjs

Comment: your server wraps the response data with `.d`. So you need to reference to the **d** property of the response data. You can also use $http interceptors to unwrap it.

Comment: i did some changes while sending data so now i do not need to use .data (.d) but the problem is that it come in single row which contain name value data pair am not able to access that data

json data is as
[{"cust_F_name":"prashant","cust_L_name":"pande"},{"cust_F_name":"nfo","cust_L_name":"sdfh"},{"cust_F_name":"Rhushi","cust_L_name":"Lokhande"},{"cust_F_name":"Rhushikesh","cust_L_name":"Lokhande"},{"cust_F_name":"werwe","cust_L_name":"werwer"},{"cust_F_name":"dsfsdf","cust_L_name":"asdf"},{"cust_F_name":"sandip","cust_L_name":"rakshak"}]

Comment: Please post it as a new question. Show how you want the data to be represented and also show what you actually get from the server.

Comment: i have add new que 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111259/unable-to-bind-json-to-list-in-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the js (the function "SimpleFactory.getCustomer()") is returning before AJAX call returning..

Also, you should use $http in Angular instead of jquery's ajax, because:

- $http returns a "promise" similar to other areas in angular, which means .success, .done are consistent with angular.
- $http set the content type to 'application/json' for you on POST requests.
- $http success and error callbacks will execute inside of angular context so you don't need to manually trigger a digest cycle - if you use jQuery, then it might be necessary to call $apply..

Like this:

```
var DemoApp = angular.module('DemoApp', []);

DemoApp.factory('SimpleFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.getCustomer = function () {
        var promise = $http.post('Home.aspx/getname', {name: ''});
        promise.catch(function(error) {
            alert(error);
        });            

        return promise;
    };

    return factory;
}]);

DemoApp.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', 'SimpleFactory', function ($scope, SimpleFactory) {
    SimpleFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
        $scope.Customer = customer;
    });    
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Factories in AngularJS are singletons. So the way you've written the code will execute the ajax call when the factory is injected into the controller. You don't see the customer data because the server response will be handled **after** you assign the *json* data to the scope variable.

A quick (and dirty) fix which will probably work is wrapping the customer object:

```
DemoApp.factory('SimpleFactory', function ($rootScope) {
  // ...
  var customer = {};
  // ...

  $.ajax({ 
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        customer.data = data;
      });
    }
    // ...
  });
});

// In view

<li data-ng-repeat="customer in Customer.data"> <!-- ... --> </li>
```

A better approach would be to use either to use the builtin [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) or the [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) angular service. The last one requires you to make use of [RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming) services (recommended). If for any reason you still want to make use of jQuery ajax calls you need some form of telling Angular that the ajax call has been completed: have a look at the [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q) promise service.

Comment: You may eventually face a $digest in progress error. http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope:inprog. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply