# Unable to bind data get from database in view using angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to take data from a database and bind it in a view using AngularJS. For that I wrote a WEM method as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getname() {
  SqlHelper sql = new SqlHelper();
  DataTable dt = sql.ExecuteSelectCommand("select cust_F_name from customer");
  Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count];
  for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
    arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
  }
  dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr);
  JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  return json.Serialize(dict);
}
```

And I call it using AngularJS:

```
var DemoApp = angular.module('DemoApp', []);
DemoApp.factory('SimpleFactory', function ($http) {
  return {
    getCustomer: function () {
      return $http.post('Home.aspx/getname', { name: "" });
    }
  };
});

DemoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, SimpleFactory) {
  SimpleFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer){
    $scope.Customer =$.parseJSON( customer.d);
  }, function(error){
    // error handling
  });
});
```

I bind it in view like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="DemoApp">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        Name<input type="text" data-ng-model="Name" />{{ Name }}
        <ul>
          <li data-ng-repeat="customerName in Customer | filter:Name">{{ customerName }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it gives me this:

[image]

Please tell me how to get the only the name from a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

#### $http methods return a promise.

By design, promises invoke callbacks with only **one argument**.

so when using `.then(function(customer) {`  , 'customer' will actually reference a promise object rather than the response body. A promise object has these properties:

1. **data** – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
2. **status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
3. **headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
4. **config** – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.

#### Solution:

```js
DemoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, SimpleFactory) {
  SimpleFactory.getCustomer().then(function(object){
    $scope.Customer = object.data.d;
  }, function(error){
    // error handling
  });
});
```

Also, You can use `success` and `error`, The arguments passed into these functions are destructured representation of the response object passed into the then method.

Read more: [$http docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Comment: it work partially it select data row now but i want access the each item in the data row in name value pair

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do parseJSON if the server is returning a valid json. Just user the result

`$scope.Customer =customer.d;`