# Unable to bind JSon to list in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, c#-4.0

i am developing an application using angular js in which i have to populate the customer list using data in database for that i write a web method to get the data like

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string  getname()
    {
        SqlHelper sql = new SqlHelper();

        DataTable dt = sql.ExecuteSelectCommand("select cust_F_name,cust_L_name from customer");

        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count];
        List<CustName> custName = new List<CustName>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            CustName c = new CustName();
            c.cust_F_name = dt.Rows[i]["cust_F_name"].ToString();            
            custName.Add(c);

        }
        dict.Add("JsonCustomer", custName);
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return json.Serialize(dict);
        //return "Rhsuhikesh";

    }

}
public class  CustName
 {
    public string cust_F_name { get; set; } 
}
```

catch that Json data as

```
var DemoApp = angular.module('DemoApp', []);

DemoApp.factory('SimpleFactory', function ($http) {
    return {
        getCustomer: function () {
            return $http.post('Home.aspx/getname', { name: "" });
        }
    };
});

DemoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, SimpleFactory) {
    SimpleFactory.getCustomer().then(function (customer) {
        $scope.Customer = customer.data;
    }, function (error) {
        // error handling
    });
});
```

and view it as

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="DemoApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Name<input type="text" data-ng-model="Name" />{{ Name }}
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="customerName in Customer | filter:Name">{{ customerName }} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I am getting o/p as

[image: outPut]

but i want it as

[image: Accepted output]

data in json i have to access in name value pair but i am not understand how to do it please help me to out if it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to me your response is JSON-serialised twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you get your results as JSON string you need to convert it to JavaScript object using **angular.fromJson**

For example:

```
DemoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, SimpleFactory) {
SimpleFactory.getCustomer().then(function (customerData) {
    var customersRawObject = angular.fromJson(customerData);
}, function (error) {
    // error handling
});})
```

Then you can do somthing like this:

```
$scope.customerA=customersRawObject.JsonCustomer[0];
```