# Using a $resource-based data model with controller and directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I have created a "model"* for my Project data like this:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory("projectModel", function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        "/api/projects/:id",
        { id: "@id" },
        {
            "update": { method: "PUT" }
        }
    );
});
```

I *don't* want the [wait-until-everything-has-loaded-before-displaying-anything behavior using `resolve` in the routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker), instead I'm happy to let the UI and data pop up when it's ready.

It would be nice to have the project data on the `$scope` in my controller, but since `projectModel` returns a *promise*, not the *data*, I need to do something like:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('EditorCtrl', function ($scope, projectModel) {

    projectModel.get({}, { 'id': session.projectId },
        function (successResponse) {
            // success callback
            $scope.project = successResponse;
        },
        function (errorResponse) {
            // failure callback
            console.log(errorResponse);
        }
    );
```

The data will be rendered in a directive, but since the directive's `link` method executes before `$scope.project` is set, I have no data to render in time. I could include `projectModel` as dependency on the directive but that feels dirty.

What's the correct way of making project data accessible to the directive?

*Bonus question: should I view my `$resource`-derived service as a MVC model, or is that confusing? If yes, what would be the best way of extending the model with helper methods etc?

Comment: I guess using `$scope.$watch()` on `$scope.project` is the right way to go...

Comment: ...or not even `$watch()`, if data bindings in my view are correctly set up. #StartingToThinkWithAngularJS

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.$watch('projectList', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal !== oldVal ) {
                    angular.forEach($scope.projectList, function (row) {
                          row.getName = function () {
                            return splitName(row.community_name);
                          };
                       });
                    }
                }, true);
```

Yes, you are right I had similar issue, you can do this by watch check for change in $scope.project and you can put the code inside it. Check the above example to update ng-grid dynamically when there is value in $scope.projectList