# load data from service before controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

Hi I'm want to load data from a factory before any of my controllers are loaded.  I found a way to do it using resolve:

```
angular.module('agent', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','general_module', 'order_module','customer_module']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/customer', {
    templateUrl: 'customer_module/partials/customer.php',
    resolve:{
      'MyServiceData':function(loginvalidation){
        // MyServiceData will also be injectable in your controller, if you don't want this you could create a new promise with the $q service
       var a=loginvalidation.check_usertype();
      }}
    }
    );
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/customer'});
}]);
```

But the problem is I would have to duplicate this with every single route.  Is there a way in angularjs to write the code once to load the service before any controller is initiated (without duplicating my code)?

Thanks

Comment: Simple approach: just factor your resolve body into a method someplace, and set resolve: myResolve() for each route. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I do, is in my controller function, I don't have any *code* at the root level. Only function declarations. See here:

```
angular.module('app').controller('TestCtrl',function($scope){

    //no code here at root level, except for some init call
    init();

    function init(){
        //some init code
        service.getSomeData().then(function(data){
            //Tell your controller to run here
            $scope.dataLoaded = true;
            doSomethingWithData(data);
        });
    }

    function addSomeWatch(){
        //some watch code here
    }

    function foo(bar){
        //something crazy
    }
});
```

The only thing that this depends on is that your service calls all return promises, which they should be doing anyways.

```
angular.module('app').factory('TestService', function(){

    return {
        getSomeData : function(){
            var d = $q.deferred();
            $http.get('someurl')
                .then(function(resp){
                    d.resolve(resp);
                });
            return d.promise;
        }
    }

});
```