# How can I get breeze to wait for metadata?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I am trying to learn Angular + Breeze (Using HotTowel.Angular and HotTowel.Angular.Breeze).

My current problem resolves around trying to hook up Breeze directly to a WCF Data Services (OData) connection (not using a BreezeController).

It seems to hook up and is calling for metadata.  But since breeze.MetadataStore().FetchMetadata returns a promise, I can't wait for it to be done.

So my app keeps plowing right along.  And it gets to a look up before the metadata is back and parsed.

**Is there someway to tell Breeze to run fetchMetadata synchronously?

 If not, then how does everyone else deal with the metadata/data race?**

Comment: Note, Breeze will get the metadata automatically.  See this answer to see what the real problem was for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23371102/16241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Q.js promise.  Breeze depends on Q.js and all of the queries return a promise.  Handle the `then` event by loading up your stuff after metadata is finished.

```
manager.fetchMetadata().then(function () { console.log('Finished, do something else'); });
```

Comment: Problem is that the first query is run on the activate method of my view.  I need my view's `activate` to wait till the metadata call is done.

Comment: I don't know how to tell angular not to activate the first view until the then call is done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker