# Angular template is showing before redirection

Tags: angularjs, grails, redirect

Im using `Grails` server side and `Angular` client side.

If the user is not allowed to access a page I redirect with `Grails` using `response.sendError(404)`

It is working but `PrivateProfileController` is calling before the redirection and it shows the template `private.html` for 1 seconds then redirecting to the template `404.html`.

Is there a way to avoid displaying `private.html` before redirecting ?

Thank you

**Grails controller's method**

```
 def privateProfile(){
     if(NOT_AUTHORIZED){
         return response.sendError(404)
     }
 }
```

**Angular**

```
app.config( ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
             '$tooltipProvider', '$compileProvider', '$httpProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $tooltipProvider, 
             $compileProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) ;
        $routeProvider
          .when('/:username/private', {
             templateUrl: '/js/angular/app/userprofile/templates/private.html',
             controller: 'PrivateProfileController'
          })
            .when('/404', {
                templateUrl: '/js/angular/app/error/404.html' , 
                controller: 'HTTPErrorController'
            })
            .otherwise({

            });

            $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(
                ['$location', '$q', function ($location, $q) {
                    function success(response) {
                        return response;
                    }

                    function error(response) {
                        if (response.status === 404) {
                            $location.path('/404');
                            return $q.reject(response);
                        }
                        else {
                            return $q.reject(response);
                        }
                    }

                    return function (promise) {
                        return promise.then(success, error);
                    }
            }]);
    }

    ]).run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',
             function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
                //console.log('Start : old', absOldUrl, 'new ',absNewUrl );
        });
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess',
             function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
               //console.log('Success : old', absOldUrl, 'new ', absNewUrl);
        });
});;

app.controller("HTTPErrorController", function ($location) {
  console.log("HTTPErrorController")
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two components acting separately asynchronously:

- rendering of the template based on the route
- XHR request responding with the authorization status.

By the time the http response is intercepted (btw response interception is [deprecated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/$http)), the route completes its part by rendering content and bootstrapping the corresponding angular controller (`PrivateProfileController`). On receiving the response, the response gets intercepted and the routing is done to /404. There comes the latency of 1 sec. (The time it took to complete the call to Grails at server side plus interception)

What can be done is making the authorization call part of [routeProvider's `resolve`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for that particular route:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/:username/private', {
       templateUrl: '/js/angular/app/userprofile/templates/private.html',
       controller: 'PrivateProfileController',
       resolve: {
           authz: function($q){
               //Create a promise
               //Call the service (REST call to Grails)
               //Get back 404
               //Reject the promise if 404
               //route to 404
               //return promise
           }
       }
    })
    .when('/404', {
       templateUrl: '/js/angular/app/error/404.html' , 
       controller: 'HTTPErrorController'
    })
    .otherwise({

    });
```

If routing to /404 is a problem inside resolve then, use [`$routeChangeError`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeError) event which gets fired on rejected promise.

Refer [**this question** answered by Misko himself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker) and this [post](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved) as well to see how resolve works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 I will check the link you provide.