# Best practice to set up a service or factory for $http contacting to REST API in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, service, controller

I've created $http and REST API interface in AnguarJS service as a function that gets injected into different controllers like this:

```
// Global service to share between states
.service("appSharedService", ['$http', function($http) {
  // Method: Returns list of all cities.
  this.restCitiesGet = function() {
     return $http.get('http://example/nkhorasaniec7/api/v0/city');
  };

  // Method:
  this.citiesGet = function() {
    this.restCitiesGet().success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
  };
}])
```

console.log(data); returns the right json output when I call citiesGet() .

```
// Main controller that prints list of cities.
.controller('CityList', ['$scope', function($scope, appSharedService) {
  $scope.cities = appSharedService.citiesGet();
  console.log($scope.cities);
}]);
```

This is my controller injecting my service. console.log($scope.cities); here returns undefined.

$scope.cities value doesn't get changed after route calls this controller.

Is there something wrong with my setup?

Something interesting is that after I change route and come back to this controller again, this time $scope.cities have my REST data and everything's fine.

I think there's something wrong with timing or asynchronous functionality problem here that I'm not aware of.

EDIT:

I could have had $http in my controller and this works all well:

```
.controller('CityList', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, appSharedService) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/nkhorasaniec7/api/v0/city').success(function (data) {
        $scope.cities = data;
      });
}]);
```

But I want to implement helper functions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

**I'm trying to make this happen in my a controller defined in my view using ng-controller**, **not a controller linked to a router** (otherwise you could use resolve property like this [Delaying AngularJS route change until model loaded to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker)).

And I want to use REST using $http as a factory/service helper function for a cleaner code.

```
// Global service to share between states
.service("appSharedService", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  this.citiesGet = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost/nkhorasaniec7/api/v0/city'}).success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }).error(function(data, status) {
        deferred.reject(data);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
  };
}])
```

I used angular $q promise here.

```
// Our main controller that prints list of cities.
.controller('CityList', ['$scope', 'appSharedService', function($scope, appSharedService) {
  var promise = appSharedService.citiesGet();
  promise.then(
        function(data){$scope.cities = data;}
        ,function(reason){alert('Failed: ' + reason);}
  );
}])
```

And used then function to use that promise.
And now it always updates $scope.cities in any situation that template loads (not just in ng-view)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the common approach would be to return the promise directly to the controller, much like you have mentioned above by directly using the http request.

```
// Global service to share between states
.service("appSharedService", ['$http', function($http) {


// Method: Returning the promise
this.citiesGet = function() {
  return $http.get('http://example/nkhorasaniec7/api/v0/city');

 };
}])
```

Controller:

```
  .controller('CityList', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, appSharedService) {
appSharedService.citiesGet().success(function (data) {
      $scope.cities = data;
    });
 }]);
```

Comment: what if I want to have .success(function(data){} as a helper function in a service or factory. What's the correct approach or best practice here?

Comment: While I think there is one, I have not personally seen a widely accepted different approach. A service is returning a promise which then is handled by the controller. However, if you feel annoyed by that style, I recommend this lecture: http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right about the timing issue. From what I understand, you are getting a promise, that at the moment you do `console.log($scope.cities)` is not yet resolved.

If you use `$scope.cities` inside your page, you should see the results as soon as they are loaded. Another option would be to use the promise `then` function if you really want to log.

```
$scope.cities = appSharedService.citiesGet().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but the weird thing is $scope.cities doesn't change on first citiesGet() call, so the view binding that. I'll try to use 'then' to see if it makes an effect

Answer (score -1):

You can use $q service

```
.service("appSharedService", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  // Method: Returns list of all cities.
  this.restCitiesGet = function() {

    var deffered = $q.defer();
     $http.get('http://example/nkhorasaniec7/api/v0/city').then(
      //success
      function(response){
         deffered.resolve(response.data);},
      //error
         deffered.reject();

      );
    return deffered 
  };
```

and after that you can use promise in you controller

```
    .controller('CityList', ['$scope', function($scope, appSharedService) {
        $scope.cities = []
       appSharedService.citiesGet().then(
        //success
        function(result){
        angular.copy(result, $scope.cities)
        console.log($scope.cities);
       }, 
      //error
      function(){
      console.log("load error");

});

    }]);
```