# AngularJs page being display before page is fully rendered

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

Having a bit of an issue, I have a page which gets routed into ng-view via a page transition. The problem is that I have a slideshow gallery which needs to be built before displaying the page.. cant seem to find a way of delaying the page transition.. I Ive read something about ngCloak and tried to put it on my home page template but doesnt seem to do anything...

Hope you guys can put me in the right direction..

homeController.js

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
.controller("homeCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-home';
    $scope.quantity = 4;

})

homeCtrl.slider = function ($timeout) {
  return {
            templateUrl: "AngularJS/views/sliderTemplate.html",
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $timeout((function() {
                return element.flexslider({
                            animation: "slide",
                            controlNav: false,
                            directionNav: true,
                            nextText: "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>",
                            prevText: "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",

                        });
                }), 0);

        }
        }
    }
};
```

Routes

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/complete", {
        templateUrl: "AngularJS/views/thankYou.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/placeorder", {
        templateUrl: "AngularJS/views/placeOrder.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/checkout", {
        templateUrl: "AngularJS/views/checkoutSummary.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/products", {
        templateUrl: "AngularJS/views/productList.html",
        controller: "productListCtrl"

    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        templateUrl: "AngularJS/views/homeView.html",
        controller: "homeCtrl"
        resolve: homeCtrl.slider
    });
})
```

Comment: When you used ng-cloak did you have the supporting CSS in place for it?

Comment: yes put the representative styles in css. issue is the page transition happens and whilst its in flow the slideshow is being built. doesnt look very nice.. need to build it then do the page transition. bit new angular js

Comment: In that case I would suggest you look at `resolve`ing your route. I would post this as an answer, though its available in a much better write-up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker

Comment: Essentially, by using the `resolve` your route won't actually change until the promise has been resolved from the controller. So you'll be able to set it up so that your route won't fire until the slideshow has been built

Comment: ok thats ill check out resolve now and get back to you all..

Comment: cant seem to get the resolve working! ill update my code now

Comment: Still have not manged to fix my issue. is there any chance one of you guys could build me a example.. would be great help thanks