# Delaying header view rendering until model loaded to prevent flicker

Tags: angularjs

My page has header, content and footer.

```
<div id='header'></div>
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
<div id='footer'></div>
```

I have binding in header section, how can I delay header view rendering until model loaded to prevent flicker ? I do not want the user to see this while ajax data is loading.

[image]

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker), it only will works for the ng-view.

My page header and footer are part of the master page, they are not governed by $routeprovider

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a conditional attribute in the header tag.

```
<div id="header" ng-show="model_name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-cloak`. It will hide the page until angularJS is ready.

Comment: I have ng-cloak on the out most div, it does not work
`<div ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
</div>`

Comment: For the head, I use directives personally, ng-cloak works only on the elements of the body. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: wrap header into a directive is a good idea. I will let you know the result. thank you!

Comment: if html dom is big, ng-cloak will not work. I have found the answer in this blog post http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jun/02/AngularJs-ngcloak-Problems-on-large-Pages