# Angular dont show view before other view is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have three views:
nav, main content, footer.

Im using ui-router and when the page is loaded the nav and the footer are loaded immiditaly, but in the main content i have a request to get some data and the view delayed a one second after the nav and footer so i stuck with empty middle content to a second. How can i do that all the views will show at the same time?

```
<div ng-include="'client/template/nav.tpl.html'"></div>
   <div class='main-wrapper'>
    <div ui-view='' class='view'></div>
   </div>
<div ng-include="'client/template/footer.tpl.html'"></div>
```

main content controller:

```
function HomeController( $scope, promos ) {

    $scope.products = products.data; // this is come from the server directly, not ajax

  }
```

One thing to notice that the data that requested to main content is not from ajax request it came from server request and its global.

Comment: use ng-clock in body.

Comment: You may want to use 'resolve': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker

Comment: use angularjs block-ui module in your app. It will block the  complete page until all the data is loaded. https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) on your template:

```
<div ng-cloak>
  <div ng-include="'client/template/nav.tpl.html'"></div>
   <div class='main-wrapper'>
     <div ui-view='' class='view'></div>
   </div>
  <div ng-include="'client/template/footer.tpl.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im using ng cloak, thats not solved my problem, ng cloak is for not to see the {{}} before they render. i want the all view not to show.