# Inject controller in $routeProvider resolve method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following the main answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker), I've tried to do the same, with the exception that my controller is isolated. 
I get this:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
ReferenceError: myController is not defined
```

I only get this when the `resolve:` parameter is present.
How can I work around this one ?

Route config:

```
 .state("my.jobs", {
                     url: "/my/:jobId",
                     templateUrl: "Views/my/index.htm",
                     controller: "myController",
                     resolve: myController.resolve  // the root of all evil here
                 })
```

controller:

```
(function (ng, app) {

    "use strict";

    var ctrl = app.controller(
        "myController",
        ['$scope', 'job',
        function ($scope, job) {
            $scope.job = job;
        }]);

    ctrl.resolve = {
        job: function ($q, $stateParams, batchService) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            jobService.loadJob($stateParams.jobId, true)
                    .then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
        },
        delay: function ($q, $defer) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $defer(delay.resolve, 1000);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    };
})(angular, myApp);
```

I don't want to make the controller a global function, I like it isolated as it is.

Comment: the example you are refering is working because it uses global variable,and your case you are making variable isolated.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned that, how can I make it work with isolated controllers

Comment: @ak is it working without resolve function()?, I'd suggest you to put your code inside angular service..and then use it..

Comment: it works without resolve function in .state definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could create one service, that you can consume inside your resolve function.

```
app.factory('resolveService', ['$q', '$stateParams', 'batchService','jobService',function($q, $stateParams, batchService,jobService ) {
    return {
        job: function($q, $stateParams, batchService) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            jobService.loadJob($stateParams.jobId, true).then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
            return delay.promise;
        },
        delay: function($q, $defer) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $defer(delay.resolve, 1000);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then the config code will be

```
.state("my.jobs", {
    url: "/my/:jobId",
    templateUrl: "Views/my/index.htm",
    controller: "myController",
    resolve: {
        resolveService: "resolveService" //this resolves to a service 
    }
});
```

For more info look at [**this reference**](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/)