# How to prevent angular to render page until all data will be present?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have following issue:
I trying to "merge" data from two collections from MongoDB.
Everything looks OK until I try to show some data from second query that came exactly after first one:

```
$scope.getData = function() {
 var pipeline, fromDateRangeStatement, toDateRangeStatement, service, joblist;
 service = ($scope.service && $scope.service.value) ? $scope.service.value : {
     $exists: true
 };
 pipeline = $scope.utils.getSessionUsersPipeline($scope.fromDate, $scope.toDate,
     $scope.checkedResults, $scope.checkedStatuses, service, $stateParams, $scope.usersLimit);
 toApi.post("/users/aggregate", {
     pipeline: pipeline
 }).success(function(data) {
     $scope.users = data.data.result;
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
         var path = "/jobs/" + scope.users[i].id + "/sessions";
         var user = $scope.users[i]
         toApi.get(path).success(function(data) {
             user.error = data.data.records[0].exception // this is not shows up in HTML!
             console.log(data.data.records[0].exception); // but it can be logged!
         })
     }
 })
```

};

So, problem is: `$scope.users` are rendered at my page, while their attribute `error` is not. Looks like data became rendered before I change attributes for every user in for loop.
How this can be handled?
Thanks

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083974/how-to-prevent-element-show-before-angularjs-initilized-ng-show  this will help you for sure

Comment: Thank you for response. But it is not helped...It still renders only $scope.users, and only then it console.log my data, that means $scope.users rendered before they updated...

Comment: You know  as per the code you need to call back error i think  Like //  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http error promise can serve your cause

Comment: Thanks, I removed .error call for make code more tiny for StackOverflow...
The problem is different - I cannot see changed data in my HTML

Comment: can you put your issue in plunker ? with some sample data i can take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are two different solutions

---

Each of your GET requests is async, so you need to wait for all of them to resolve. You could wrap each request in its own Promise and collect all Promises like so

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
  promises[i] = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var path = "/jobs/" + scope.users[i].id + "/sessions";
    var user = $scope.users[i]
    toApi.get(path).success(function(data){
      user.error = data.data.records[0].exception;
      console.log(data.data.records[0].exception);
      resolve(user);
  })
}
```

Then use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to group all promises together as one Promise and wait for it to resolve.

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(users) { 
  $scope.users = users;
});
```

Quick example: http://codepen.io/C14L/pen/QNmQoN

---

Though, a simpler and better solution would be to display the users one after one, as their API calls return

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
  var path = "/jobs/" + $scope.users[i].id + "/sessions";
  toApi.get(path).success(function (data) {
      $scope.users[i].error = data.data.records[0].exception;
      $scope.users[i].done = true;
      console.log(data.data.records[0].exception);
  });
}
```

Simply add into your template a check for `$scope.users[i].done = true` and ony show that dataset with `ng-show="user.done"`.

Comment: Seems simple, but it throws error:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'error' of undefined:
It cannot see $scope.users for some reason

Comment: Fixed it, for some reason the for loop was using $scope.jobs.length. Also, fixed "/jobs/" + scope. --> "/jobs/" + $scope.

Comment: Head Slap I Missed async part . C14L Thumbs Up!! :-)

Comment: Amazing guys! Thanks, you all helped me! Now it works. I also binded value in HTML code, now it is rendered pretty as I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

`var user = $scope.users[i]` only assign the value of `$scope.users[i]`. so later when you do `user.error=...`, it is not going to change the `$scope`. try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.jobs.length; i++) {
  var path = "/jobs/" + scope.users[i].id + "/sessions";
  toApi.get(path).success(function(data){
    $scope.users[i].error = data.data.records[0].exception // this is not shows up in HTML!
    console.log(data.data.records[0].exception); // but it can be logged!
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 elements about handling this :

If you use {{value}} replace this by

```
<span ng-bind="value"></span>
```

So you won't see brackets.

Now you want to wait for all your request before changing anything in order to not have partial data displayed. This is easy too :

```
var promiseArray = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
     var path = "/jobs/" + scope.users[i].id + "/sessions";
     var user = $scope.users[i]
     promiseArray.push(toApi.get(path)).success(function(data){
         var result = {i:i, data:data};
         return result
     });
 }
 $q.all(promiseArray).then(function success(result){
     for(var i=0; i < promiseArray.length;i++){
        $scope.users[result.i].error = result.data.data.records[0].exception;
     }
 });
```

Bascially i'm waiting for all request to be resvoled before changing any data so this will run in the same angular loop. So the DOM will be only refreshed once and the user won't see any partial results.